# Generate a list of field types assiged to record types

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, custom-field, mobile, record-type

Im a bit new to Salesforce so maybe this is trivial or maybe im incorrect about some stuff below

My end goal here is to provide a report of fields that are available via Salesforce Web (Classic) and Salesforce1, as an initial assessment

Now obviously things are more complicated, for example an object like Account has upto 20 record types and upto 300 fields. I'd like to provide a report for the Account object, with a listing of record types and which of these fields are accessible in Salesforce1 only and web only and both

I solved one challenge by using an app called [EasyDescribe](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ) but that only gives me a list of fields and list of record types for an object

Can someone suggest how I should go about determining which fields map to which record types? And then if there can be a non-manual way to determine which fields are visible on Web vs Salesforce1 vs both?

Im fairly familiar with programming, so Im totally ok writing code for this, but it would be great if someone can tell me what I should start looking at if i were to code this. Im very new to Salesforce

Comment: Wait. Fields don't map to Record Types, Pagge Layouts do.  Did you try going through the PL assignments?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, you're right and actually thats what i need since Im trying to determine the difference in the detail pages on the web vs salesforce1 app. Can you tell me if there is a programmatic way to get page layout assignments for record types of an object?